# How to choose snowboard bag size?

Tags: equipment, snowboarding

I have a snowboard (Borton TWC Standard 12-13) **157 cm**. I want to buy Wheelie Gig Bag (http://www.burton.com/default/wheelie-gig-bag/F14-10994100.html?cgid=mens-board-bags). This bag is available in sizes: 146 152 156 162 166. There is no 157 size.

What size should I take and why?

Comment: Not to turn you away from here, there's definitely going to be someone that can provide you with advice. But, as a heads up, most outdoors/skiing, snowboarding shops employees are pretty well trained, and could also give you some good hints :-)

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. This question seems to represent a [shopping recommendation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Not knowing much about snowboarding, would a bag bigger than your snowboard (ie, 162cm) suffice, or does it **have** to be the same length? I believe your question asks this, in part, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You should go with the 162 size if you feel that you are done growing and won't need a bigger snowboard anytime soon. That way you won't have to buy a new bag if you outgrow your snowboard.

Answer (score -1):

I'd go with the **biggest one you can find so you can jam a ton of extra stuff in there**, which winds up being incredibly helpful come travel-time.

Plus, I've **stitched a second grab handle onto the bottom of some of my wheelie bags, right at the level where my board would end inside of the bag**. That lets me roll up the extra length if I don't need it and still have a smaller wheelie.